# Sharing and running Xcode project not require signing

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to have an Xcode project run without a signing profile. I am submitting code for a competition and would like the judges to not have to worry about signing. This app will never be distributed anywhere, only run from Xcode.

Basically: Can somebody download and run a project without touching this stuff: 
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the instructions for the competition. There is some chance that they provide the UUID of a few test iPads in which case you might be expected to do an AdHoc build for them.

As the other answer stated they can just run in the simulator but it is also easy for them to change the bundle ID to a profile they have themselves. In this case, just make sure you never actually access you own bundle ID at runtime and do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they load the project through the simulator it should be fine. Otherwise if you want your project to be loaded on a physical device you will need a signing certificate

Comment: Nonono they can't build because they don't have the certificate and password.